# In laravel 9, unauthenicated route not retrieving data from database

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, docker, web

Im using laravel 9, and have working authentication where logged in users can view, edit and delete records from a database. I have achieved this using ajax

I also want users that aren't logged in to be able to view these records but only add to them, not edit or delete them.

However, even though the view for the unauthenticated users has the exact same code as the view used for logged in users, none of the data shows up for the unauthenicated users whereas when you are logged in the data is shown.

When I'm logged in I'm accessing all the CRUD routes through 'comments-crud'

when I'm not logged in I'm trying to access the same route just to a different page guest-view.blade.php to use the same database information

## Logged in users

When a user clicks login from the homepage and successfully logs in they are redirected to a dashboard where they can select this comments tab and see the data

## Non logged in users

and users that aren't logged in are supposed to see the same thing as the logged in users, just without the ability to delete, update or verify comments

## This is the web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\Activity;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentController;

Route::get('guest-view', [CommentController::class, 'index'])->name('guest-view');
Route::post('save-comment', [CommentController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('fetch-comments', [CommentController::class, 'fetchComment']);


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth','verified'],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
Route::get('comments-crud', [CommentController::class, 'index'])->name('comments-crud');
Route::post('save-comment', [CommentController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('fetch-comments', [CommentController::class, 'fetchComment']);
Route::get('edit-comment/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('update-comment/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('delete-comment/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'destroy']);

Route::get('/activity', function(){
    Mail::to('me@somewhere.come')->send(new Activity());
    return redirect('dashboard');
})->name('activity');

});






require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

## This is the navigation.blade.php file

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
    <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
            <div class="flex">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="shrink-0 flex items-center">
                    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
                        <x-application-logo class="block h-10 w-auto fill-current text-gray-600" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Navigation Links -->
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                    </x-nav-link>
                    <x-nav-link :href="route('comments-crud')" :active="request()->routeIs('comments-crud')">
                        {{ __('Comments') }}
                    </x-nav-link>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
            <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6">
                <x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        <button class="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                            @auth
                            <div>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
                            @endauth

                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Log Out') }}
                            </x-dropdown-link>
                        </form>

                            <div class="ml-1">
                                <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        <!-- Authentication -->
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Log Out') }}
                            </x-dropdown-link>
                        </form>
                    </x-slot>
                </x-dropdown>
            </div>

            <!-- Hamburger -->
            <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                <button @click="open = ! open" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path :class="{'hidden': open, 'inline-flex': ! open }" class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                        <path :class="{'hidden': ! open, 'inline-flex': open }" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
    <div :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': ! open}" class="hidden sm:hidden">
        <div class="pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
            <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                {{ __('Dashboard') }}
            </x-responsive-nav-link>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
            <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('comments-crud')" :active="request()->routeIs('comments-crud')">
                {{ __('Comments') }}
            </x-responsive-nav-link>
        </div>

        <!-- Responsive Settings Options -->
        <div class="pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-200">
            <div class="px-4">
                @auth
                <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
                <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->email }}</div>
                @endauth
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3 space-y-1">
                <!-- Authentication -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('logout')"
                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                        this.closest('form').submit();">
                        {{ __('Log Out') }}
                    </x-responsive-nav-link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

## And this is the CRUD view comments-crud.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Comment Bank</title> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<x-app-layout>

<div class="container mt-2">
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>


<div class="row">


<div class="col-md-12 card-header text-center font-weight-bold">
<h2>Comment Bank</h2>
</div>


<div id="message"></div>


<div class="col-md-12 mt-1 mb-2"><button type="button" id="addNewComment" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="Table1" class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope ="col">Message Select</th>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">Comment Body</th>
<th scope="col">First Name</th>
<th scope="col">Last Name</th>
<th scope="col">Email</th>
<th scope="col">Comment Tone</th>
<th scope="col">Comment Type</th>
<th scope="col">Verified Status</th>
<th scope="col">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 


</tbody>
</table>
<input id = "btnGet" type="button" value="Get Selected" />


</div>
</div> 
<div><textarea id="messageList" rows="10" cols="100">Selection</textarea> <button type="button" id="copy">Copy</button></div>


</div>



<!-- boostrap model -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comments-crud-model" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title" id="commentsCrudModel"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


<ul id="msgList"></ul>



<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="addEditCommentForm" name="addEditCommentForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Comment Body</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<textarea class="form-control" id="comment_body" name="comment_body" rows="4" cols="10">Enter Comment Body</textarea>
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Comment Tone</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment_tone" name="comment_tone" placeholder="Enter Tone" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Comment Type</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment_type" name="comment_type" placeholder="Enter Comment Type" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Verified Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="verified_status" name="verified_status" placeholder="Enter Verified Status" value="" required="">
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add" value="addNewComment">Save
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="UpdateComment">Save changes
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</x-app-layout>


<!-- end bootstrap model -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){


fetchComment(); // Get the table from the dB to start


$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
function fetchComment()
{
// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: "fetch-comments",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
// console.log(res);
$('tbody').html("");
$.each(res.comments, function (key, item) {
$('tbody').append('<tr>\
<td><input type="checkbox" name="comments_to_copy" id="comments_to_copy' +item.id+'"/></td>\
<td>' + item.id + '</td>\
<td>' + item.comment_body + '</td>\
<td>' + item.first_name + '</td>\
<td>' + item.last_name + '</td>\
<td>' + item.email + '</td>\
<td>' + item.comment_tone + '</td>\
<td>' + item.comment_type + '</td>\
<td>' + item.verified_status + '</td>\
<td><button type="button" data-id="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-primary edit btn-sm">Edit</button>\
<button type="button" data-id="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-danger delete btn-sm">Delete</button></td>\
</tr>');
});
},
complete: function(){
isChecked();
}
});
}


$('#addNewComment').click(function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();


$('#addEditCommentForm').trigger("reset");
$('#commentsCrudModel').html("Add Comment");
$('#btn-add').show();
$('#btn-save').hide();
$('#comments-crud-model').modal('show');
});


$('body').on('click', '#btn-add', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var comment_body = $("#comment_body").val();
var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var comment_tone = $("#comment_tone").val();
var comment_type = $("#comment_type").val();
var verified_status = $("#verified_status").val();
$("#btn-add").html('Please Wait...');
$("#btn-add").attr("disabled", true);
// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "save-comment",
data: {
comment_body:comment_body,
first_name:first_name,
last_name:last_name,
email: email,
comment_tone: comment_tone,
comment_type: comment_type,
verified_status: verified_status,
},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
console.log(res);
if (res.status == 400) {
$('#msgList').html("");
$('#msgList').addClass('alert alert-danger');
$.each(res.errors, function (key, err_value) {
$('#msgList').append('<li>' + err_value + '</li>');
});
$('#btn-save').text('Save changes');
} else {
$('#message').html("");
$('#message').addClass('alert alert-success');
$('#message').text(res.message);
fetchComment();
}
},
complete: function(){
$("#btn-add").html('Save');
$("#btn-add").attr("disabled", false);
$("#btn-add").hide();
$('#comments-crud-model').modal('hide');
$('#message').fadeOut(4000);
}
});
});
$('body').on('click', '.edit', function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');


// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: "edit-comment/"+id,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
console.dir(res);
$('#commentsCrudModel').html("Edit Comment");
$('#btn-add').hide();
$('#btn-save').show();
$('#comments-crud-model').modal('show');
if (res.status == 404) {
$('#msgList').html("");
$('#msgList').addClass('alert alert-danger');
$('#msgList').text(res.message);
} else {
// console.log(res.book.xxx);
$('#comment_body').val(res.comment.comment_body);
$('#first_name').val(res.comment.first_name);
$('#last_name').val(res.comment.last_name);
$('#email').val(res.comment.email);
$('#comment_tone').val(res.comment.comment_tone);
$('#comment_type').val(res.comment.comment_type);
$('#verified_status').val(res.comment.verified_status);
$('#id').val(res.comment.id);
}
}
});
});
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
if (confirm("Delete Comment?") == true) {
var id = $(this).data('id');
// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"DELETE",
url: "delete-comment/"+id,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
// console.log(res);
if (res.status == 404) {
$('#message').addClass('alert alert-danger');
$('#message').text(res.message);
} else {
$('#message').html("");
$('#message').addClass('alert alert-success');
$('#message').text(res.message);
}
fetchComment();
}
});
}
});
$('body').on('click', '#btn-save', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var id = $("#id").val();
var comment_body = $("#comment_body").val();
var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var comment_tone = $("#comment_tone").val();
var comment_type = $("#comment_type").val();
var verified_status = $("#verified_status").val();
// alert("id="+id+" title = " + title);
$("#btn-save").html('Please Wait...');
$("#btn-save").attr("disabled", true);
// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"PUT",
url: "update-comment/"+id,
data: {
comment_body:comment_body,
first_name:first_name,
last_name:last_name,
email: email,
comment_tone: comment_tone,
comment_type: comment_type,
verified_status: verified_status,
},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
console.log(res);
if (res.status == 400) {
$('#msgList').html("");
$('#msgList').addClass('alert alert-danger');
$.each(res.errors, function (key, err_value) {
$('#msgList').append('<li>' + err_value + '</li>');
});
$('#btn-save').text('Save changes');
} else {
$('#message').html("");
$('#message').addClass('alert alert-success');
$('#message').text(res.message);
fetchComment();
}
},
complete: function(){
$("#btn-save").html('Save changes');
$("#btn-save").attr("disabled", false);
$('#comments-crud-model').modal('hide');
$('#message').fadeOut(4000);
}
});
});
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
var message = "";


//Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in GridView.
$("#Table1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
// message += row.cells[2].innerHTML;
message += " " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
// message += " " + row.cells[4].innerHTML;
message += "\n-----------------------\n";
});


//Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
$("#messageList").html(message);
return false;
});


$("#copy").click(function(){
$("#messageList").select();
document.execCommand("copy"); 
alert("Copied On clipboard");
});


function isChecked(){
$("#Table1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 1)
{
$(this).prop("checked", true);
}
else
{
$(this).prop("checked", false);
}
});
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## This is the controller code for CommentController.blade.php

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Comment;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function index()
{
return view('comments-crud');
}

```
public function fetchComment()
{
    $comments = Comment::all();
    return response()->json([
        'comments'=>$comments,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'comment_body'=>'required',
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'comment_tone'=>'required',
        'comment_type'=>'required',
        'verified_status'=>'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>400,
            'errors'=>$validator->messages()
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->comment_body = $request->input('comment_body');
        $comment->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $comment->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $comment->email = $request->input('email');
        $comment->comment_tone = $request->input('comment_tone');
        $comment->comment_type = $request->input('comment_type');
        if ($request->has('verified_status')){
            $comment->verified_status = 1;
        }
        else{
            $comment->verified_status = 0;

        }
        
        $comment->save();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'message'=>'Comment Added Successfully.'
        ]);
    }
}
  
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Product  $product
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{   
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    if($comment)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'comment'=> $comment,
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>404,
            'message'=>'No Comment Found.'
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Update an existing resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Product  $product
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'comment_body'=>'required',
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'comment_tone'=>'required',
        'comment_type'=>'required',
        'verified_status'=>'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>400,
            'errors'=>$validator->messages()
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        $comment = comment::find($id);
        if($comment)
        {
            $comment->comment_body = $request->input('comment_body');
            $comment->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
            $comment->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
            $comment->email = $request->input('email');
            $comment->comment_tone = $request->input('comment_tone');
            $comment->comment_type = $request->input('comment_type');
            $comment->verified_status = $request->input('verified_status');
            $comment->update();
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>200,
                'message'=>'Comment with id:'.$id. ' Updated Successfully.'
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>404,
                'message'=>'No Comment Found.'
            ]);
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Product  $product
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    if($comment)
    {
        $comment->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'message'=>'Comment Deleted Successfully.'
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>404,
            'message'=>'No Comment Found.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

}

I've tried migrating the tables again and seeding again but the data still doesn't show.

Comment: You could look into a system using permissions and roles. https://websolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-9-user-role-and-permission. Using roles u can protect specific parts of your code like the ability to delete, update en verify comments

Comment: would that be compatible with my ajax though?